# Powershell mail message script

Tags: email, powershell, send

I'm having a problem with a script.

Every night, the server task scheduler runs a batch that creates a log on which PCs it couldn't update. This PS script then pulls the error log and sends an email notifying us of the PCs. The error log file is a .txt file and the name of the file changes everyday to reflect the date, for example, 10172016.txt.

I can get the script to email and it used to pull the log file and place it into its body; but now, it's blank and shows an error regarding "+".

Code:

```
clear

$smtpserver = "test.test.org"

$from="noreply@test.org"

$to="adamh@test.org"

$subject="Update Error Log for" + " " + (get-date -format d)

$message = (Get-Content -path "\\testserver\Departments\IT\Private\test\logs" + "(get-date -f mmddyyyy)" + ".txt" | Out-String )

$mailer = new-object Net.Mail.SMTPclient($smtpserver)

$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage($from,$to,$subject,$body)

$msg.IsBodyHTML = $false

$mailer.send($msg)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is (at least) a problem with your code, namely (command simplified):

```
Get-Content -path "\path\to\" + "(get-date -f MMddyyyy)" + ".txt"
```

It needs to be (note the enclosing parentheses and the absence of double quotes around the `get-date` command):

```
Get-Content -path ("\path\to\" + (get-date -f MMddyyyy) + ".txt")
```

PowerShell has **two fundamental parsing modes** - ***argument* mode** and ***expression* mode**, and **understanding which is applied when is important**: 
see [`Get-Help about_Parsing`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847892.aspx).

In short: Without `(...)`, PowerShell sees `"\path\to\" + (get-date -f MMddyyyy) + ".txt"` as *5 separate* arguments rather than a single, synthesized string.

---

Alternatively, you could use a single double-quoted string with **string interpolation** that uses the **subexpression operator, `$(...)`**, to embed the `get-date` call:

```
Get-Content -path "\path\to\$(get-date -f MMddyyyy).txt"
```

---

Additional observations:

- A native [`Send-MailMessage`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx) is available since PowerShell version 3.
- The format string for 2-digit months is `MM`, not `mm` (the latter is *minutes*).
- While using pseudo method syntax `new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage($from,$to,$subject,$body)` happens to work, it's better to avoid it, because it can mask a misconception of how `New-Object` works: The proper form is `New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage -ArgumentList $from,$to,$subject,$body`; as you can see, because you're dealing with a *cmdlet*, it uses *argument* mode.

Comment: You've solved the riddle. Thank you! It was the a mixture of both of your suggestions.

Comment: @AdamHerrera: Glad to hear it. In what way did you have to use a mixture? I've added a few more notes to the answer.